# How to select the whole list view and extract the whole content?

Tags: android, arrays, google-maps, listview, sms

My app reads the messages from the phone's inbox and displays it on a list view in the app. These messages contain coordinates to be displayed in google map. I can extract the content one by one already and when i click the selected list view row, the marker will be shown on the google map. Now what i wanna do is, since there are many coordinates in the list view, i want to be able to extract all the coordinates in one go and display it on google maps, so it will show many markers on google map and then ill poly line it. Do i need to use array? How do i go about this?

Here's my main activity codes:

```
public class MainActivity extends AppCompatActivity implements         OnClickListener {

//  GUI Widget
Button getSmsButton, viewGoogleMapButton;
TextView lblMsg, lblNumber;
ListView messageListView;
Context ctx = this;
String msg;
String lat, lng, latTag = "latTag", lngTag = "lngTag";
double latd, lngd;


// Cursor Adapter
SimpleCursorAdapter adapter;

@Override
protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
    setContentView(R.layout.activity_main);

    // Init GUI Widget
    getSmsButton = (Button) findViewById(R.id.getSmsButton);
    getSmsButton.setOnClickListener(this);

    messageListView = (ListView) findViewById(R.id.messageListView);


    viewGoogleMapButton = (Button) findViewById(R.id.viewGoogleMapButton);
    viewGoogleMapButton.setOnClickListener(new OnClickListener() {
        @Override
        public void onClick(View view) {

            Intent startGoogleMap = new Intent(ctx, MapsActivity.class);
            startActivity(startGoogleMap);


        }

    });

    messageListView.setOnItemClickListener(new AdapterView.OnItemClickListener() {
        @Override
        public void onItemClick(AdapterView<?> parent, View view, int position, long id) {

            //for getting the position
            String data=messageListView.getItemAtPosition(position).toString();

            //for getting the text from selected item
            TextView textView = (TextView) view.findViewById(R.id.lblMsg); //textView in your listView
            String text = textView.getText().toString();
            //Log.i("msg", text);

            String[] coordinate = text.split(", ");
            lat = coordinate[0];
            lng = coordinate[1];

            latd = Double.parseDouble(lat);
            lngd = Double.parseDouble(lng);

            Intent passVariable = new Intent(ctx, MapsActivity.class);
            passVariable.putExtra(latTag,latd);
            passVariable.putExtra(lngTag,lngd);
            startActivity(passVariable);
        }
    });

}

@Override
public void onClick(View v) {

    if (v == getSmsButton) {

        // Create Inbox box URI
        Uri inboxURI = Uri.parse("content://sms/inbox");

        // List required columns
        String[] reqCols = new String[]{"_id", "address", "body"};

        // Get Content Resolver object, which will deal with Content Provider
        ContentResolver cr = getContentResolver();


        // Fetch Inbox SMS Message from Built-in Content Provider
        Cursor c = cr.query(inboxURI, reqCols, null, null, null);

        // Attached Cursor with adapter and display in listview
        adapter = new SimpleCursorAdapter(this, R.layout.row, c,
                new String[]{"body", "address"}, new int[]{
                R.id.lblMsg, R.id.lblNumber});
        messageListView.setAdapter(adapter);



    }

}
}
```

here's my google maps activity codes:

```
public class MapsActivity extends FragmentActivity implements OnMapReadyCallback {

private GoogleMap mMap;
String latTag = "latTag", lngTag = "lngTag";
double latd, lngd;
@Override
protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
    setContentView(R.layout.activity_maps);
    // Obtain the SupportMapFragment and get notified when the map is ready to be used.
    SupportMapFragment mapFragment = (SupportMapFragment) getSupportFragmentManager()
            .findFragmentById(R.id.map);
    mapFragment.getMapAsync(this);
}


/**
 * Manipulates the map once available.
 * This callback is triggered when the map is ready to be used.
 * This is where we can add markers or lines, add listeners or move the camera. In this case,
 * we just add a marker near Sydney, Australia.
 * If Google Play services is not installed on the device, the user will be prompted to install
 * it inside the SupportMapFragment. This method will only be triggered once the user has
 * installed Google Play services and returned to the app.
 */
@Override
public void onMapReady(GoogleMap googleMap) {
    mMap = googleMap;
    mMap.setMapType(GoogleMap.MAP_TYPE_NORMAL);

    Bundle extras = getIntent().getExtras();
    if (extras != null) {
        latd = extras.getDouble(latTag);
        lngd = extras.getDouble(lngTag);
    }

    // Add a marker in Singapore and move the camera
    LatLng singapore = new LatLng(latd, lngd);
    /*LatLng singapore0 = new LatLng(1.3347954, 103.7760273);
    LatLng singapore1 = new LatLng(1.3350862, 103.7765259);
    LatLng singapore2 = new LatLng(1.3347714, 103.776533);
    LatLng singapore3 = new LatLng(1.3345733, 103.776867);
    LatLng singapore4 = new LatLng(1.334255, 103.775617);
    LatLng singapore5 = new LatLng(1.333447, 103.7752314);
    LatLng singapore6 = new LatLng(1.332072, 103.774257);
    LatLng singapore7 = new LatLng(1.330976, 103.775757);
    LatLng singapore8 = new LatLng(1.332358, 103.777676);*/

    mMap.addMarker(new MarkerOptions().position(singapore).title("Marker in Singapore"));
    /*mMap.addMarker(new MarkerOptions().position(singapore0).title("Marker in Singapore"));
    mMap.addMarker(new MarkerOptions().position(singapore1).title("Marker in Singapore"));
    mMap.addMarker(new MarkerOptions().position(singapore2).title("Marker in Singapore"));
    mMap.addMarker(new MarkerOptions().position(singapore3).title("Marker in Singapore"));
    mMap.addMarker(new MarkerOptions().position(singapore4).title("Marker in Singapore"));
    mMap.addMarker(new MarkerOptions().position(singapore5).title("Marker in Singapore"));
    mMap.addMarker(new MarkerOptions().position(singapore6).title("Marker in Singapore"));
    mMap.addMarker(new MarkerOptions().position(singapore7).title("Marker in Singapore"));
    mMap.addMarker(new MarkerOptions().position(singapore8).title("Marker in Singapore"));*/

    mMap.addPolyline((new PolylineOptions())
            .add(singapore));
                    //singapore0, singapore1, singapore2, singapore3, singapore4, singapore5, singapore6, singapore7, singapore8));

    mMap.moveCamera(CameraUpdateFactory.newLatLngZoom(singapore,16));
}
```

}

here's my row xml file codes:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<LinearLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
android:orientation="vertical" android:layout_width="match_parent"
android:layout_height="match_parent">

<TextView
android:textAppearance="?android:attr/textAppearanceLarge"
android:text="TextView"
android:layout_width="wrap_content"
android:layout_height="wrap_content"
android:id="@+id/lblMsg"></TextView>

<TextView
android:textAppearance="?android:attr/textAppearanceMedium"
android:text="TextView"
android:layout_width="wrap_content"
android:layout_height="wrap_content"
android:textColor="#00f"
android:id="@+id/lblNumber"></TextView>

</LinearLayout>
```

Answer (score 0):

This is how I solved when I wanted to plot multiple markers. First create a model class to hold the lat and long coordinates and then create a List of that. This way:

```
    public class LatLong {

    private Double lat;
    private Double lng;
    private String name;
    private String address;

    /**
     *
     * @return
     * The lat
     */
    public Double getLat() {
        return lat;
    }

    /**
     *
     * @param lat
     * The lat
     */
    public void setLat(Double lat) {
        this.lat = lat;
    }

    /**
     *
     * @return
     * The lng
     */
    public Double getLng() {
        return lng;
    }

    /**
     *
     * @param lng
     * The lng
     */
    public void setLng(Double lng) {
        this.lng = lng;
    }

    public String getName()
    {
        return name;
    }

    public void setName(String name)
    {
        this.name = name;
    }

    public String getAddress()
    {
        return address;
    }

    public void setAddress(String address)
    {
        this.address = address;
    }

    }
```

Then inside your `MapsActivity` :

```
private List<LatLong> list_location;
```

Then pass the data to this list as `Parcelable` or in your own preferred way. Once you have the data, this is how you plot it :

```
 @Override
public void onMapReady(GoogleMap map) {

    for(LatLong x:list_location)
    {
        map.moveCamera(CameraUpdateFactory.newLatLngZoom(new LatLng(x.getLat(),x.getLng()), 15));
        map.addMarker(new MarkerOptions()
                .title(x.getName())
                .snippet(x.getAddress())
                .icon(BitmapDescriptorFactory.fromResource(R.drawable.dine))
                .position(new LatLng(x.getLat(),x.getLng())));
    }


    MapStyleOptions style = MapStyleOptions.loadRawResourceStyle(
            this, R.raw.style_json); // ignore this if you are not using the map with a custom design
    map.setMapStyle(style);
}
```

Comment: for the main activity, does that extract all the coordinates in my list view? where in my codes do i place it?